# How to extract heading tags in php

Tags: php, wordpress

in wordpress when I use `<?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' ); ?>` it works
but if I have a different php output like this one `<?php echo $variable['custom_title_option']; ?>` how can I do the same as on the_title

also if I use a function like the below example:

```
function change_hading_titles() {
global $variable; 
$heading_tag = $variable['custom_title']; //option name
if ($heading_tag == "h1") {
print '<h1>', '</h1>';
} elseif ($heading_tag == "h2") { 
print '<h2>', '</h2>';
} elseif ($heading_tag == "h3") { 
print '<h3>', '</h3>';
} elseif ($heading_tag == "h4") { 
print '<h4>', '</h4>';
} elseif ($heading_tag == "h5") { 
print '<h5>', '</h5>';
} elseif ($heading_tag == "h6") { 
print '<h6>', '</h6>';
}
}
add_action('change_hading_titles', 'change_hading_titles');
```

is it possible to use `do_action( 'change_hading_titles' );` to change all my custom titles?
So, I mean to retrieve the function for closing `<?php echo $variable['custom_title_option']; ?>` with heading tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
function getTag($tagName, $titleValue){

    return "<".$tagName.">".$titleValue."</".$tagName.">";

}

$tag = getTag("h1", "hello");
// $tag = <h1>hello</h1>
```

..If that is not what your after, please explain a little more clearly, am happy to help further. Either way, this would be a significantly more efficient way of doing that function.

Comment: thanks Caspar you gave me a good idea I will try to change this for my needs,however let me explain it better.The function in my question is retrieving the select option from redux framework settings and echo $variable['custom_title_option']; is just a custom title coming with another text option from redux again but I want to close it in heading tags choosen from the function but Im not so expert in php

Comment: Okay - i think i understand. I have updated my answer. You can now give the tag a title/value. So put the title_option in as the second argument and it will be closed in the desired tags specified in the first argument

Comment: Thankyou Caspar, your function helped me for other functions too I was using if else statements everywhere but with your code you helped me too much to make my functions shorter.Thanks